# request for Tex math markup on the site

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

A lot of us will probably be writing a lot of mathematical content, from signal processing equations to dynamic modeling. I think the site could benefit greatly from the ability to use [Math Jax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), as the math and signal processing sites do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mahjax has been enabled on this site.

Comment: Many thanks @Geoff.

Comment: Just a note, MathJax here uses the `$` delimiter which is how it is on most SE sites. The exception being EE.SE which uses `\$` as it's delimiter and this note being most applicable to people coming solely from that site.

Answer (score 5):

I would tend to agree, when we are talking about control theory [Math Jax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) would be very useful. I have already linked to wikipedia pages who's content I wouldn't be able to inline without *Math Jax* support.

As it was, my links were an aside, background reading, so I didn't need to inline the content, but it would be nice to have this before someone does need it and has to prepare images or break out the ascii art to add formulae. *8')